# nvd3, linePlusBarWithFocusChart shows same value for multiple bars of different items

Tags: angularjs, nvd3.js

I am trying for Bar chart with Focus for Date Range series. As there is no predefined directive for this on krispo nvd3 directives website, I tried to use linePlusBarWithFocusChart, where line chart is hidden. But the bars are not appearing with correct data. Even though multiple bars appearing (with accurate color schemes) but each bar shows same data. How can I fix this so that the bars appear with correct data? Please find my plunker at http://plnkr.co/edit/rsB9MwvT0doRTmBOUOXE?p=preview. I have used the correct mapping function.

```
.map(function(series) {
                series.values = series.values.map(function(d) { return {x: d[0], y: d[1] } });
                return series;
            });
```